# Does the compact manifold $f=0$ resist small perturbations?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose we have a compact manifold of the form $\left\{f=0\right\}$ where $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth Morse function.

I am interested in showing that the manifold is topologically resistant to small perturbations of the function $f$. I would like a result of the following type:

> $\left\{f = 0 \right\}$ is homeomorphic to $\left\{f+g=0\right\}$ under certain conditions on $g$ of type "$g$ is very small" and "$g$ is very smooth".

For example, if $g$ is a small constant function then I know how to prove it, but this condition is too restrictive. If $g$ is only continuous, then I know it is false and how to construct a counterexample. I would be happy if it can be proven with the conditions: $g$ is smooth, $\sup |g|$ is very small, $\sup |\nabla g|$ is very small.

Comment: Just a little thought: you could use Ehresmann's theorem for the smooth functions $g$ such that a) for some $\varepsilon>0$, $Y:=\{(x,t) | f(x)+tg(x) = 0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\times (-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ is smooth and b) the projection $Y\to (-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon)$ is proper submersive and surjective, which should in this case be equivalent to fibres being non-empty compact.

Comment: My idea has an issue... Unfortunately, I don't see how to make sure the projection is proper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your hope is true. Let $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$ : $M$ is the unit circle. For all $\epsilon>0$, let $g_\epsilon$ be a smooth function with support in $D(1+\epsilon, \epsilon/2)$, such that $g_\epsilon(1+\epsilon,0)=-f(1+\epsilon,0)=1-(1+\epsilon)^2=-2\epsilon-\epsilon^2$. We can construct $g_\epsilon$ so that there is a constant $K$ independant from $\epsilon$ so that $|\nabla g_\epsilon| \leq K \epsilon$.

However, $\{f+g_\epsilon = 0\}$ cannot be homeomorphic to a circle, since it is the disjoint union of a circle and something else (in particular it is not connected).

EDIT

there is a mistake, we can only ask that $|\nabla g_\epsilon| \leq K$ and not $K \epsilon$

EDIT 2

We can make it work with $f(x)=x^2$ and $g_\epsilon=-\epsilon x$ on $[0,\epsilon]$
(we can extend $g_\epsilon$ in such a way that it is smooth and small, with small derivative (uniformly). Then $f+g_\epsilon$ vanishes at $x=\epsilon$ so there is at least one more point and the topology is not preserved.

I can add more detail if necessary.

Note : Here we use a perturbation near a critical point. The wanted result might be true if we ask that $f$ is a submersion.

Comment: This doesn't work. If such a $g_\epsilon$ exists, then $g_\epsilon(1+\epsilon,0) = -2\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ (note sign correction) and $g_\epsilon(1,0)=0$, so the mean-value theorem implies there is some $a\in (1,1+\epsilon)$ such that $\partial g_\epsilon/\partial x(a,0) = (g_\epsilon(1+\epsilon,0) - g_\epsilon(1,0))/\epsilon = -2-\epsilon$. Thus $|\nabla g_\epsilon|$ cannot go to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: This example is more or less what I meant when I said I know how to construct a counterexample if you only assume continuity. The issue with adding a "tiny bump" is that the perturbation would have to change very quickly in a small area which means its gradient cannot be small.

Comment: @JackLee ah my bad, you are right.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein though note that in this example the $g_\epsilon$ can be chosen smooth